# if condition in html editable table

Tags: php, html, mysql

i want to display only distinct non-numeric values in html table. The table must be editable and the user could edit the table and edited data must be stored in the databas. This is what im trying without if condition it displays only distinct values of first column and repeat other column values. Answers will be appreciated.

```
$sql= "select distinct 
                ,CASE WHEN col1 not regexp '[0-9]' THEN col1 else null end as col1
                ,CASE WHEN col2 not regexp '[0-9]' THEN col2 else null end as col2
                ,CASE WHEN col3 not regexp '[0-9]' THEN col3 else null end as col3
                from table_name";

                $run_sql= mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

                while ($rows= mysqli_fetch_array($run_sql)) {
                echo "
                        <tr> 
                            <td>".if ($rows['two']!= NULL){
                            $rows['two']
                            }."</td>
                            <td>".if ($rows['three']!= NULL){
                            $rows['three']
                            }."</td>
                            <td>".if ($rows['four']!= NULL){
                            $rows['four']
                            }."</td>
                        </tr>"; 
                }
```

Comment: `if` is not a function call and has no return value. What you're doing is not valid php. you cannot have `if()` "return" something and use it elsewhere.

Comment: @MarcB yeah i know im doing wrong, could you please tell me the right way.

Comment: why have the `if` in the first place? if the value from the DB is null, it'll print as a zero-length string anyways. `echo "<td>$rows[one]</td><td>$rows[two]</td>etc...";`

Comment: `while ($rows= mysqli_fetch_array($run_sql)) {
               
     echo "<tr><td>";
        
     if ($rows['two']!= NULL){
      echo $rows['two'];
     }
     echo "</td><td>";
     if ($rows['three']!= NULL){
      echo $rows['three'];
     }
     echo "</td><td>";
     if ($rows['four']!= NULL){
      echo $rows['four'];
     }
     echo "</td></tr>"; 
                }`

Comment: @MarcB yeah i was doing same but that was displaying only first column with distinct values and the other column if had 2 distinct values then all was repeating again and again because of first column distinct values. i hope you got me. thanks

Comment: @MarcB this displays the distinct values of col2, col3 multiple times because col1 is longer than these so it is repeating other columns is there is any other technique.

Comment: I can't really follow your description. Could you give an example of how the output should look like?

Comment: @Philipp like this:
  col1 | col2 | col3
    a        bb    cc
    b        ww   rr
    c
    d
The above code displays like this: 
  col1 | col2 | col3
    a         bb    cc
    b         ww   rr
    c         bb    cc
    d         ww   rr

Comment: Also the sql query is just plain invalid. `DISTINCT` is a keyword and must be followed by a/multiple column/s, not by a `,`